# CSS, Bootstrap, HTML - Shrink responsive Images to get equal size in the row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am kind of new in web design and I am having issues to properly resize images with the class img-fluid in a certain view where they act as some kind of thumbnails inside a portfolio-item. I am going to upload a couple of images to explain what I am trying to achieve. The first image is what I am trying to do, around 3-4 items per row with the same size , the problem is that when I show one image that is vertically bigger than horizontally it also gets bigger resolution than the other images , messing my row entirely and adding some empty spaces [image: Image 1]

This second image ilustrates the problem, 2 is the image that is bigger in height and it messes the other elements depending on the position that image gets placed.
[image: Image 2]

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
                <!-- Portfolio item -->
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <a class="portfolio-link" href="someurl">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="sourceofimage" alt="default" height=auto/>
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">some text</div>
                        <div class="portfolio-caption-subheading text-muted">some text</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS of img-fluid

```
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: if they cant have a fixed size, you could use `flex:1;` and make the image `object-fit:cover;` the container, in bootstrap 5 its `.flex-fill` dont know about lower versions

Comment: looks like this did the job, thanks @Breezer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use both `height` and `width`. Set the width to how ever many pixels or any other increment you would like, and the same for the height.

The code: https://codepen.io/flvffywvffy/pen/OJjoeKP (ignore the javascript)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the most accurate one since I can't do that with @Breezer's answer. A mix of both lead me to the solution. Thanks to everyone who replied to my question